# conditonal formatting working on lists and not libraries?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery

Any reason why this code works on a list in a page and not on the list of pages (Pages library - PAGES) displayed on a page?

The 'cell' (ms-vb2) is the same in both cases.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("td.ms-vb2").each( function () {
    if($(this).text() == "Red"){
    $("td .ms-vb2:contains('Red')").css("background-color", "#e81123");
       }    
    if($(this).text() == "Amber"){
    $("td .ms-vb2:contains('Amber')").css("background-color", "#ff8c00");
       }  
    if($(this).text() == "Green"){
    $("td .ms-vb2:contains('Green')").css("background-color", "#00B294");
       }    
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This should work. Just check values of column in pages library.

Comment: The Red, Amber Green are in both cases choice fields

Comment: Yes it should still work. It works in my environment with your exact code. Any error messages in console ?

Comment: did you apply the code to a page library (the publishing page library called pages). On the same page I have the list and the pages library and it works only in one. Console says nothing relevant

Comment: Yes , I have added listview webpart on https://****.sharepoint.com/sites/***/Pages/Forms/AllItems.aspx It works here as well.

Comment: my view uses the feature 'group by' and this is the element that makes the script not work, not sure why. Can you group yours by a parameter? (any...)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work by going into the properties of the webpart and selecting Enable Asynchronous Update, Enable Asynchronous Automatic Refresh, Enable Data View Caching and Server Render. Not sure which one made the trick. Any ideas?

Comment: It was probably Server Render. That forces the server to do the work of composing the list view into HTML for you, delivering it whole once it's ready; otherwise it's rendered by JavaScript asynchronously. Note that switching to Server Render will disable some functionality, such as client side rendering (jslink templates).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your code runs first and then table renders in case when you use group by :

Your code needs to run post rending table (data).Sharepoint execute '*ProcessImn*' function post rendering your group data.Run your code after ProcessImn. It will apply your style. Eg below :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <script type="text/javascript">
function GroupDataLoads()
{
    ApplyColorCoding();
    var oldExpand = ProcessImn;
    ProcessImn = function(){
        var results = oldExpand.apply(this, arguments);
        ApplyColorCoding();
        return results;
    }
}

function ApplyColorCoding()
{
       $("td.ms-vb2").each( function () {
    if($(this).text() == "Red"){
    $("td .ms-vb2:contains('Red')").css("background-color", "#e81123");
       }    
    if($(this).text() == "Amber"){
    $("td .ms-vb2:contains('Amber')").css("background-color", "#ff8c00");
       }  
    if($(this).text() == "Green"){
    $("td .ms-vb2:contains('Green')").css("background-color", "#00B294");
       }    
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){ 
GroupDataLoads();
});
<script>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's document ready function loads immediately after the DOM has been loaded. For calling a function after SharePoint's body is loaded, you can use the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('YourFunction');
    function YourFunction() {
        console.log("test");
    }
</script>
```

OR

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(yourFunctionName, "sp.js");
function yourFunctionName () {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Your code integrated with the functions above:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('ApplyColorCode');
    function ApplyColorCode() {
        $("td.ms-vb2").each( function () {
            if($(this).text() == "Red"){
                $("td .ms-vb2:contains('Red')").css("background-color", "#e81123");
            }    
            if($(this).text() == "Amber"){
                $("td .ms-vb2:contains('Amber')").css("background-color", "#ff8c00");
            }  
            if($(this).text() == "Green"){
             $("td .ms-vb2:contains('Green')").css("background-color", "#00B294");
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Same way you can try the other one.

Comment: so you mean I should put one of your codes above inside my code?

Comment: In place of 'YourFunction' or 'YourFunctionName', you can call your function. I mean whatever you have qritten inside document ready, just write it in a function and call that function in place of 'YourFunction'

Comment: I do not know what is the name of 'myfunction'. You need to tell me where to put your code inside mine or in a separate script

Comment: Check the edited answer

Comment: it does not work, no colour is shown

Comment: run this in the console on Pages library and share the result please. -> $("td.ms-vb2")
I tried it and it returned just 1 'td' element. It should return an array to make your code work.

Comment: I removed some of the options to the webpart and now it shows even when grouped. I left the server render checkbox

Comment: So it works then? or you still need a solution?

Comment: I did not need the additional script to act after the page was loaded. I just needed to tick server render and the colours were displayed even with items grouped. I prefer it to the additional codes, which btw never worked.

Answer (score 0):

For the list view with group by, we can use the following code to achieve it.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
    var overrideCurrentContext = {};
    overrideCurrentContext.Templates = {};
    overrideCurrentContext.OnPostRender =colorField;
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCurrentContext);
})();

function colorField(ctx) {
    $("td.ms-vb2").each( function () {
        if($(this).text().indexOf("Red")!=-1){
            $(this).css("background-color", "#e81123");
        }    
        if($(this).text().indexOf("Amber")!=-1){
            $(this).css("background-color", "#ff8c00");
        }  
        if($(this).text().indexOf("Green")!=-1){
            $(this).css("background-color", "#00B294");
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

[image]